# Problem with generating WebService proxy using svcutil

Tags: wsdl, wcf-client, svcutil.exe

In our application we are forced to consume several WebServices. In the beginning we used just the "Add Service Reference" menu option, in order to create a WCF proxy.

The wizard didn't generate a DataContract, but much rather an XML-Serializable class. So far, so bad, but this wasn't the killer. However, later we noticed, that we were losing data, because the generated proxy was adding the Order property when attributing and this was causing problems.

Now we are trying to generate proxy classes from the WSDL using the SVCUTIL.EXE, but we are all the time getting the following error message:

```
    C:\temp\WSDL>svcutil /serializer:DataContractSerializer ReadSddsAddressOut.wsdl
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchKanton']/wsdl:input


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchKanton']/wsdl:output


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchPlz']/wsdl:input


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchPlz']/wsdl:output


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchNation']/wsdl:input


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchNation']/wsdl:output


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchAdr']/wsdl:input


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchAdr']/wsdl:output


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchPkt']/wsdl:input


Warning: Das optionale WSDL-Erweiterungselement "body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" wurde nicht behandelt.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://post.ch/sdds/address']/wsdl:binding[@name='ReadSddsAddressOutBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='GeoSuchPkt']/wsdl:output


Generating files...
C:\temp\WSDL\ReadSddsAddressOut.cs
C:\temp\WSDL\output.config
```

The error message in English looks like this

"The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled."

The original WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ReadSddsAddressOut" targetNamespace="http://post.ch/sdds/address" xmlns:p2="http://post.ch/sdds" xmlns:p1="http://post.ch/sdds/address" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:documentation/>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://post.ch/sdds" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://post.ch/sdds">
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoKantonReq">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="maxRows" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoPktReq">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOSTRBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRCMT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORX" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORY" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORZ" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPKTMAIN" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="withDeletedPkt" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="maxRows" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoNationResp">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DataSet">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoKantonResp">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DataSet">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoPlzResp">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DataSet">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZONRP" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD1" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD2" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT18" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT27" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZTYP" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSTATUS" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoPktResp">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DataSet">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTID" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORX" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORY" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTKORZ" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTSTK" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTWOH" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTMAIN" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOSTRBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOSTRTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNR" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRHAUSN" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRGEBFLG" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRLAGFLG" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRCMT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRHAUSKEY" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRGPOID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZONRP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD1" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD2" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT18" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT27" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPKTSTATUS" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoPlzReq">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="maxRows" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoNationReq">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="maxRows" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoAdrResp">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                        <xsd:element name="ErrorText" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DataSet">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRID" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOSTRBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOSTRTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNR" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRHAUSN" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRGEBFLG" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRLAGFLG" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRCMT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRHAUSKEY" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRGPOID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZONRP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD1" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZSPRCOD2" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT18" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT27" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZTYP" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEONATBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                                <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTATUS" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                    </xsd:element>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ZuboGeoAdrReq">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRID" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNID" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOKTNBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZPLZ4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOPLZORT39" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOSTRBEZ" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRSTRNRT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="GEOADRCMT" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="withDeletedAdr" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xsd:element name="maxRows" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoKantonReq">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoKantonReq" element="p2:ZuboGeoKantonReq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoKantonResp">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoKantonResp" element="p2:ZuboGeoKantonResp"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoPlzReq">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoPlzReq" element="p2:ZuboGeoPlzReq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoPlzResp">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoPlzResp" element="p2:ZuboGeoPlzResp"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoNationReq">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoNationReq" element="p2:ZuboGeoNationReq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoNationResp">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoNationResp" element="p2:ZuboGeoNationResp"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoAdrReq">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoAdrReq" element="p2:ZuboGeoAdrReq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoAdrResp">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoAdrResp" element="p2:ZuboGeoAdrResp"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoPktReq">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoPktReq" element="p2:ZuboGeoPktReq"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="p2.ZuboGeoPktResp">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:part name="ZuboGeoPktResp" element="p2:ZuboGeoPktResp"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ReadSddsAddressOut">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchKanton">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoKantonReq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoKantonResp"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchPlz">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoPlzReq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoPlzResp"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchNation">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoNationReq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoNationResp"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchAdr">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoAdrReq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoAdrResp"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchPkt">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoPktReq"/>
            <wsdl:output message="p1:p2.ZuboGeoPktResp"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ReadSddsAddressOutBinding" type="p1:ReadSddsAddressOut">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchKanton">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchPlz">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchNation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchAdr">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GeoSuchPkt">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ReadSddsAddressOutService">
        <wsdl:port name="ReadSddsAddressOutPort" binding="p1:ReadSddsAddressOutBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://h03kyq:51000/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?channel=:SDDS_DEV:ssReadSddsAddress" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And the (screwed) proxy class looks like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Dieser Code wurde von einem Tool generiert.
//     Laufzeitversion:2.0.50727.3074
//
//     Änderungen an dieser Datei können falsches Verhalten verursachen und gehen verloren, wenn
//     der Code erneut generiert wird.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://post.ch/sdds/address", ConfigurationName="ReadSddsAddressOut")]
public interface ReadSddsAddressOut
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void GeoSuchKanton();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void GeoSuchPlz();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void GeoSuchNation();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void GeoSuchAdr();

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
    void GeoSuchPkt();
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public interface ReadSddsAddressOutChannel : ReadSddsAddressOut, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public partial class ReadSddsAddressOutClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ReadSddsAddressOut>, ReadSddsAddressOut
{

    public ReadSddsAddressOutClient()
    {
    }

    public ReadSddsAddressOutClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public ReadSddsAddressOutClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public ReadSddsAddressOutClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public ReadSddsAddressOutClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public void GeoSuchKanton()
    {
        base.Channel.GeoSuchKanton();
    }

    public void GeoSuchPlz()
    {
        base.Channel.GeoSuchPlz();
    }

    public void GeoSuchNation()
    {
        base.Channel.GeoSuchNation();
    }

    public void GeoSuchAdr()
    {
        base.Channel.GeoSuchAdr();
    }

    public void GeoSuchPkt()
    {
        base.Channel.GeoSuchPkt();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's actually the problem? All I see are warnings, rather than errors (and you might want to translate them for us *grin*)

Even adding order attributes should not cause lost data unless the service on the other side is making bad assumptions.

Comment: By adding the Order clause, WCF automatically assumes, that every single attribute WILL be shown. This is not necessarily the case, especially since the minoccur is 0.

The problem is, that those warnings mean, that the generator skipped the types completely, generating void ...(void) methods, which it should not, they all have an input and an output type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The schema used by the wsdl does not conform to the Data Contract Serializer's [Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx).

Problems:

1. "All elements must be qualified for a schema to be supported by DataContractSerializer".

   Your schema omits the elementFormDefault attribute on the  tag so the default, "unqualified" is in effect.  You need to add the following attribute name/value pair to the <schema> element so that the Data Contract Serializer (DCS) can resolve the local elements/types.

   **elementFormDefault="qualified"**
2. maxOccurs and minOccurs attributes on <sequence> tag must be 1 or omitted (default is 1).

   So, remove maxOccurs="unbounded" on the <sequence>.
3. Add maxOccurs="unbounded" on the <row> tag to get a nested collection data contract generated for the DataSet field.

   For example,

   `<xsd:element name="DataSet">
     <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`

Comment: It's like Mr. Svcutil Exe himself answered the question. Why can't he talk like this when I use him?

Answer (score 0):

I had to get rid of the use of "element" and much rather just used the "complexType"s.

So I removed the enclosing elements on the DataContracts and in the Messages, I set the type attribute instead of the element attribute. Now it works, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure how you generated your wsdl and stuff, but datasets has a few oddities.

When generating my proxy with a ds I need to reference this assembly:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll

Cheers,
Stian