# optional WSDL extension element 'annotation' from namespace was not handled

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, svcutil.exe

> Custom tool warning: The optional WSDL extension element 'annotation'
>   from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' was not handled.
>   XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://soap.vindicia.com/v3_6/Account']/wsdl:binding[@name='AccountBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='fetchByMerchantAccountId']

When I try to add this wsdl to my project in Visual Studio(2010) (using add service reference), I get this warning. I don't quite understand this error. Can someone please explain me what is the problem here and why is Visual Studio complaining ?

Webservice is located here: https://soap.prodtest.sj.vindicia.com/3.6/Account.wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema used by the wsdl does not conform to the Data Contract Serializer's Schema Reference.

Please refer to [Problem with generating WebService proxy using svcutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906082/problem-with-generating-webservice-proxy-using-svcutil).